# Renamed root in /etc/passwd and now sudo does not work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root, passwd

I accidentally modified the line for root in /etc/passwd and changed its named. To fix it I tried using sudo to modify this file, but it does not let me sudo because sudo can't find the root user since I renamed it.

II am on ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try :

```
sudo -u new_wrong_root_user
```

If you can't, reboot on a live-cd, then in terminal :

```
mkdir target
mount /dev/sda1 target # sda1 if / is the first partition of the first drive
vim target/etc/passwd
```

Comment: sudo -u worked.